# linker command failing for particular golang test involving "net/http" and "time" packages

Tags: macos, go, macos-big-sur

I'm new to web development and golang. I'm trying to learn go from [here](https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests/). Without any issues I was able to learn till [concurrency](https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests/go-fundamentals/concurrency) part, however, I'm facing issues while trying to learn [select](https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests/go-fundamentals/select) statements. Here is what I did. `hello.go` contains the function, while `hello_test.go` has the testing code. This is the `hello.go` code.

```
package lol

func Racer(a, b string) (winner string) {
    return
}
```

Below is the testing code

```
package lol

import "testing"

func TestRacer(t *testing.T) {
    slowURL := "http://www.facebook.com"
    fastURL := "http://www.quii.co.uk"

    want := fastURL
    got := Racer(slowURL, fastURL)

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("got %q, want %q", got, want)
    }
}
```

The test is failing just as expected with message `hello_test.go:13: got "", want "http://www.quii.co.uk"`. Now I'm trying to write some more code to `hello.go` to make it pass.

```
package lol

import(
    "time"
    "net/http"
)

func Racer(a, b string) (winner string) {
    startA := time.Now()
    http.Get(a)
    aDuration := time.Since(startA)

    startB := time.Now()
    http.Get(b)
    bDuration := time.Since(startB)

    if aDuration < bDuration {
        return a
    }

    return b
}
```

When I'm testing now, it is giving me `# runtime/cgo ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64 clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) FAIL    module [build failed]`. After searching on internet forums on this error, I did `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and reinstalled them back, but didn't help. I think it may be due to the modules I'm trying to import but I'm not sure. I don't know if it is relevant or not but I updated to macOS Big Sur two days before facing the issue. Please help in resolving the issue. TIA

Edit: go env is returning

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/{user_name}/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/{user_name}/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/{user_name}/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/{user_name}/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="/Users/{user_name}/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar"
CC="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang"
CXX="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/zc/4r25vdyj4cv3ynjx64633ly40000gn/T/go-build3491450963=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Edit 2:
The test started working when I ran `CGO_ENABLED=0 go test -v ./...`. It returned the expected output.

```
=== RUN   TestRacer
    hello_test.go:13: got "http://www.facebook.com", want "http://www.quii.co.uk"
--- FAIL: TestRacer (2.52s)
FAIL
FAIL    module  3.076s
FAIL
```

I'm still trying to understand why I need to add `CGO_ENABLED=0` to for this particular test.

Comment: Which Go compiler are you using? Is it a reasonably modern version? Did you follow https://golang.org/doc/install?

Comment: I followed the documentation for installation. How can I check Go compiler? I'm running it is vscode

Comment: open a terminal and execute `go version` which results in something like this `go1.16.3 darwin/amd64`

Comment: `go version go1.16.5 darwin/amd64`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are running the test within the vscode UI. To remove as many causes as possible, try to build the code and run the tests directly from the terminal. Learning to use the Go tools independently from an IDE gives you power :-)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue even after running directly from terminal

Comment: What does `go build -v -x .` say?

Comment: `# runtime/cgo
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. It's throwing the same error

Comment: Looks like the C compiler defined in `go env` has problems, maybe (re-)installing xcode helps: Command `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was **R Studio** installed through Anaconda package manager. After it was removed, the linker started working as expected.